# i am using php 5.6.24 in xamp and i'm installing V8js extension and getting following warning

Tags: php, php-ini

## php -i | findstr "Thread"

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: v8js: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Thread Safety => enabled

Comment: The version of v8js does not appear to be compatible with your version of PHP. They both appear to be using a different MSVC runtime library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed the wrong version of the extension. You need the version that is compiled with API `20131226`. So you have to search for the correct version and install them. Then is should work.

https://github.com/terrylinooo/v8js-dll

here you can see the versions that are included. So normally if you have used the correct version it should be correct.

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: v8js: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20131226,TS,VC12
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20131226,TS,VC11    can you please give me link for API20131226,TS,VC11??